# Modificar nombre de columna de un DataGridView que hereda datos desde DataSource de una base de datos - WindowsForm C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, windows-forms, sql-server-2008

primero pido disculpas si no he sido muy claro en el título.

- Tengo una base de datos, dentro de ella una tabla con 4 columnas que almacenan datos.
- Tengo mi propia clase que administra la base de datos, donde la lectura de datos la hago a partir de un método y la almaceno en un objeto de tipo DataTable.
- Cargar esos datos almacenados en el DataTable a un DataGridView, es simple utilizando la propiedad DataSource, hasta acá está todo entendido.

La ayuda que necesito es para cambiar el nombre de las columnas heredadas desde la tabla de la DB, no puedo lograr nada.

Código en el form:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Database.QuerySQL.readData();
    }
```

Código que ejecuta las Query en su propia clase

```
    public static DataTable readData()
    {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM Historial";

        myTable.Load(Database.executeReader(Query));

        Database.disconnectDB();

        return myTable;
    }
```

Código que ejecuto en mi clase de Database

```
    public static SqlDataReader executeReader(string Query)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(conSTR);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);

        con.Open();

        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Lo que yo quiero es que, al mostrarse los datos, los nombres de las columnas no me aparezcan como en la base de datos (**EJEMPLO**: codigo_ARTICULO), sino mostrarlo asi -> (**EJEMPLO**: CODIGO ART).

Visual Studio - C#
SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer eso que buscas deberias usar la propiedad `HeaderText` de las columnas de la grid para indicar el texto que quieres que aparezca en cada una de ellas.

Ejemplo:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "CODIGO ART";
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias, ha quedado justo como necesitaba.